# HTTP Response automatically revised by read() of BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, urllib

I'm trying to run the following code but noticed that the text of `bsObj1` was revised to blank text after I extracted its contents by `read()`. `bsObj3` was also revised to blank text while I didn't do anything to it.

Why would `bsObj1` and `bsObj3` become blank? How to prevent `bsObj1` to be changed automatically?

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def getLinks(pageUrl):
    html1 = urlopen(pageUrl)
    html2 = urlopen(pageUrl)
    html3 = html1

    body1 = html1.read()

    bsObj1 = BeautifulSoup(html1)
    bsObj2 = BeautifulSoup(html2)
    bsObj3 = BeautifulSoup(html3)

    print("bsObj1's length is "+str(len(bsObj1.text)))
    print("bsObj2's length is "+str(len(bsObj2.text)))
    print("bsObj3's length is "+str(len(bsObj3.text)))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    getLinks("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page")
```

Output:-

```
bsObj1's length is 0
bsObj2's length is 16000
bsObj3's length is 0
```

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe you have a typo in code . you have read html1 already so when you parse it to BeautifulSoup it will read nothing because `body1 = html1.read()`.  has read html1 already same goes for `html3` as it is equal to `html1`

so following code works fine .

```
body1 = html1.read()

bsObj1 = BeautifulSoup(body1)
bsObj2 = BeautifulSoup(html2)
bsObj3 = BeautifulSoup(body1)
```

**Sample Output**

bsObj1's length is 16028

bsObj2's length is 16028

bsObj3's length is 16028

Hope this helps .

Comment: Thanks! It's not a typo but I don't know `read()` would change `html1` since I thought I was just extracting its contents. For `html3`, I tried `html3.__repr__()` and noted that the memory address of it is same as `html1`. Is there a way to copy the object only but not share the same address?

Comment: here is something you should read if you want to know about copying objects :https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html